# Is this an error in my tensorflow installation or is it alright to run codes with the following error?

Tags: tensorflow

I already had tensorflow and CUDA installed, but I had to downgrade both of them for certain reasons. I tried my best for installation but I get the following output:

```
>>> import tensorflow
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:523: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint8 = np.dtype([("qint8", np.int8, 1)])
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:524: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint8 = np.dtype([("quint8", np.uint8, 1)])
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:525: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint16 = np.dtype([("qint16", np.int16, 1)])
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:526: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_quint16 = np.dtype([("quint16", np.uint16, 1)])
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:527: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  _np_qint32 = np.dtype([("qint32", np.int32, 1)])
/home/hrushikesh/.virtualenvs/mytraya/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/dtypes.py:532: FutureWarning: Passing (type, 1) or '1type' as a synonym of type is deprecated; in a future version of numpy, it will be understood as (type, (1,)) / '(1,)type'.
  np_resource = np.dtype([("resource", np.ubyte, 1)])
>>> import tensorflow
>>> import tensorflow
```

If this is not an error, is there any way I can prevent it from, I tried 
`os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'` but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This warning should not be a problem. It looks like, in the version you are using, some code was deprecated (meaning it is no longer the preferred way to use it) in part of the library and not all of the other parts of the library were updated yet. This warning should not affect your training.